# JSON dump for User defined class in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dump, user-defined-types

Here is how I want my data to be : (key=name, value=[dob,[misc1, misc2,..]])

```
    # my sample code
inputNames = [
('james', ['1990-01-19', ['james1', 'james2', 'james3'] ]),
('julie', ['1991-08-07', ['julie1', 'julie2'] ]),
('mikey', ['1989-01-23', ['mikey1'] ]),
('sarah', ['1988-02-05', ['sarah1', 'sarah2', 'sarah3', 'sarah4'] ])
]
class empData (list):
    def __init__ (self, misc=None):
            list.__init__([])
            # print('add empdata: ',misc[0],misc[1])
            self.dob = misc[0]
            self.extend(misc[1])
    def edprint(self):
            return(self.dob, self)
class myEmp():
    def __init__ (self, anm, amisc=None):
            self.nm = anm
            self.details = empData(amisc)
    def printme(self):
            print(self.nm, self.details.edprint())

emps={}
for i in inputNames:
    m = myEmp(i[0],i[1])
    emps[m] = m
print(emps) 
# prints addresses of variables

# for actual data use the following lines
for ea in emps:    
    emps[ea].printme() 

try:    
   with open('data.json','w') as wfd:
             json.dump(emps, wfd)              
except IOError as ioerr:
            print('File error: ',str(ioerr))
wfd.close()
```

The above gives me an error: TypeError: key <**main**.myEmp object at 0x10143d588> is not a string
I am unable to figure out how to dump my dict of myEmp data structures as JSON

Comment: Em, not strange if You are trying to dump something what is not of standard accepted type : 
You are creating your own class **myEmp** so how JSON cann know how to represent this object ? You could create custom JSONEncoder as doc says, or set skipkeys to True if you want to just pass this error.

Comment: I did that too: 
    class myEmpEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, obj):
            if isinstance(obj, myEmp):
                return [obj.nm, obj.details]
                # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
And called it as:
    json.dump(ms, wfd, cls=myEmpEncoder)

I still get Error: TypeError: key <__main__.myEmp object at 0x101bf5940> is not a string

Comment: And logically what I am doing is dumping a dict of my employees "emps" to JSON. The key is the employee name and employee details are an arbitrary list. So shouldn't python be able to dump the dict?

Comment: Nope problem is in DICT key , You are using something thats is not a string look :

    m = myEmp(i[0],i[1])
    emps[m] = m

For dict it's legal coz repr of obect is hashable but, dump needs to know how to translate whole objct to KEY not to json object itself.

Comment: Ah my bad!
Typo:
The line is supposed to be amps[m.nm]=m
That means that the key is a string(m.nm) and the value is a class of myEmp

Answer (score -1):

Before you can dump to `json` you need explicitly convert your data to a serializable type like `dict` or `list`. You could do this using a list comprehension:

```
>>> d = [{'key':ea.nm, 'value':[ea.details.dob, ea.details]} for ea in emps]
>>> json.dumps(d)
'[{"value": ["1991-08-07", ["julie1", "julie2"]], "key": "julie"}, {"value": ["1989-01-23", ["mikey1"]], "key": "mikey"}, {"value": ["1990-01-19", ["james1", "james2", "james3"]], "key": "james"}, {"value": ["1988-02-05", ["sarah1", "sarah2", "sarah3", "sarah4"]], "key": "sarah"}]'
```

Comment: This looks reasonable - I was hoping for a method that could help me understand if there is something wrong with my understanding of dict